# Network Configuration Reset & Bridge wlan1 to eth0

Tags: networking, wifi

So I want to connect to the Internet with my Raspberry Pi, but I can't. I am using SSH (ethernet) to give it commands but it just won't work. I have tried to bridge my wlan1 external adapter (TP-Link) from my neighbor's WiFi (have got permission to do that), bridge it to Ethernet so I can connect it to a router that will make the connection wireless on my house.

The problem is that I've read a bunch of tutorials but have messed up the network configurations a lot.

When I execute: `ifconfig`

This is what I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:30:cc:67  
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e87:202e:734f:bb07/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:80635 (78.7 KiB)  TX bytes:18032 (17.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:20736 (20.2 KiB)  TX bytes:20736 (20.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:65:99:32  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:7 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1073 (1.0 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:e3:27:0d:e2:92  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I can't even connect to the Internet first, to do `apt-get update` etc. - how do I reset all my network configurations to default?

And after that, how do I get the wlan1 adapter to bridge the network over to Ethernet, so I can plug it into the router right away?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it's time to start from scratch and pay attention to what you do next time.

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is that I've read a bunch of tutorials but have messed up the network configurations a lot" doesn't help tell what you ACTUALLY did.

Forget bridging, which is advanced configuration.

Try following the steps in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) to setup your WiFi.

Comment: I just followed these steps, but my ifconfig output remained the same. I try ping google.com but no luck.

I must've done:
`echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE`

which is what must have messed the wlan0 & wlan1 configuration. Is there any way I can reset that? @Milliways

Comment: "these steps" is meaningless - if you are referring to my tutorial this describes at least 3 different approaches. If you want any help you need to post the contents of your config files (into your question NOT comments).